# LDAP JAVA : Searching in many OU=... in the active directory

Tags: java, eclipse, active-directory

I want to do a global research in my browser. I have 5 folder and I want have all the solution present in these 5 folders.

Someone have an idea ?

```
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

             Attributes matchAttrs = new BasicAttributes(true); // ignore attribute name case

             matchAttrs.put(new BasicAttribute("mail");

             // Search for objects that have those matching attributes
             NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("DC=corp", matchAttrs);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Reformulate your question.

Comment: Ok : I have folder that contains 5 other folders. How can I find all the "CN". I do like "ou=BigFolderWhoContains5Other" but it just print the CN present in the big folder and not the CN present in the 5 folders

Answer (score 0):

Ok dunno why but my function `searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);` didn't work.

Here it's working.

Sorry for helper and sorry for my reputation :D